# Implementing C# IEnumerable<T> for a LinkedList class

Tags: c#, mono, monodevelop

I'm trying to write a custom LinkedList class in C# using monoDevelop on Linux, just for the sake of testing and learning. The following code never compiles, and I have no idea why!! It doesn't even tell me what's wrong. All what it says is: Error: The compiler appears to have crashed. Check the build output pad for details. When I go to check the output pad, it's not helpful either: 
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: The specified field must be declared on a generic type definition.
Parameter name: field

What can I do?

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace LinkedList
{
    public class myLinkedList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
    {
        //List Node class
        //===============
        private class ListNode<T>
        {
            public T data;
            public ListNode<T> next;

            public ListNode(T d)
            {
                this.data = d;
                this.next = null;
            }

            public ListNode(T d, ListNode<T> n)
            {
                this.data = d;
                this.next = n;
            }
        }

        //priavte fields
        //===============
        private ListNode<T> front;
        private int size;

        //Constructor
        //===========
        public myLinkedList ()
        {
            front = null;
            size = 0;
        }


        //public methods
        //===============
        public bool isEmpty()
        {
            return (size == 0);
        }

        public bool addFront(T element)
        {
            front = new ListNode<T>(element, front);
            size++;
            return true;
        }

        public bool addBack(T element)
        {
            ListNode<T> current = front;
            while (current.next != null)
            {
                current = current.next;
            }

            current.next = new ListNode<T>(element);
            size++;
            return true;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            ListNode<T> current = front;
            if(current == null)
            {
                return "**** Empty ****";
            }
            else
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                while (current.next != null)
                {
                    sb.Append(current.data + ", ");
                    current = current.next;
                }
                sb.Append(current.data);

                return sb.ToString();
            }
        }

        // These make myLinkedList<T> implement IEnumerable<T> allowing
        // a LinkedList to be used in a foreach statement.
        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return new myLinkedListIterator<T>(front);
        }


        private class myLinkedListIterator<T> : IEnumerator<T>
        {
            private ListNode<T> current;
            public virtual T Current
            {
                get
                {
                    return current.data;
                }
            }
            private ListNode<T> front;

            public myLinkedListIterator(ListNode<T> f)
            {
                front = f;
                current = front;
            }

            public bool MoveNext()
            {
                if(current.next != null)
                {
                    current = current.next;
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            public void Reset()
            {
                current = front;
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                throw new Exception("Unsupported Operation");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably should not throw exception in `Dispose` since it is going to be called by `Foreach` loops if I remember correctly.

Comment: It is entirely incorrect to throw in the Dispose(); it is, however, allowed to throw in `Reset()`; no standard API will ever use `Reset()` - it is essentially deprecated.

Comment: Oh, btw - `Node<T>` should ***not*** be generic inside `LinkedList<T>`; generic type parameters are inherited - this can be simply `Node`. The compiler warns you about this: "Type parameter 'T' has the same name as the type parameter from outer type 'LinkedList.myLinkedList<T>'"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to add the non-generic APIs; so add to the iterator:

```
object System.Collections.IEnumerator.Current { get { return Current;  } }
```

and to the enumerable:

```
System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    return GetEnumerator();
}
```

HOWEVER! If you are implementing this by hand, you are missing a trick. An "iterator block" would be much easier.

The following is a **complete** implementation; you don't need to write an enumerator class ***at all*** (you can remove `myLinkedListIterator<T>` completely):

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    var node = front;
    while(node != null)
    {
        yield return node.data;
        node = node.next;
    }
}
System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    return GetEnumerator();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried what you suggested and it worked only when I separated the classes (myLinkedList, ListNode, myLinkedListIterator) into separate files. I guess there was a conflict between the generic type parameter <T> that I used for these classes.

Comment: @AhmedFakhry well, see also the comment I added on the post; the `T` in `ListNode<T>` is **incorrect and redundant**. This is a *compiler bug*, though - it should have compiled even with the redundant `T`. Try removing the `T` in `ListNode<T>`, keeping them in the same file

Answer (score 5):

When i tried the code that you have pasted i get 2 errors when trying to build.

> myLinkedList' does not implement interface member
>   'System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()'.
>   '.myLinkedList.GetEnumerator()' cannot implement
>   'System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()' because it does not
>   have the matching return type of 'System.Collections.IEnumerator'.

Solution is to implement the following in the first class.

```
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
```

And the second error is :

> myLinkedList.myLinkedListIterator' does not implement interface
>   member 'System.Collections.IEnumerator.Current'.
>   'JonasApplication.myLinkedList.myLinkedListIterator.Current'
>   cannot implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerator.Current' because it
>   does not have the matching return type of 'object'.

Solution to the second could be something as following to implement in the second class.

> object IEnumerator.Current
>               {
>                   get { return Current; }
>               }