# Implementing IEnumerable to my object

Tags: c#, ienumerable, ienumerator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Implementing C# IEnumerable<T> for a LinkedList class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12069205/implementing-c-sharp-ienumerablet-for-a-linkedlist-class)

After searching the web for some hours now I still can't understand how `IEnumerable`/`IEnumerator` works and how to implement it.

I've constructed a simple `LinkedList` from scratch but now I want to implement `IEnumerable` for it so I can foreach it.  How do I do that?

```
class Program
{
    LL myList = new LL();

    static void Main()
    {
        var gogo = new Program();
    }
    public Program()
    {

        myList.Add("test");
        myList.Add("test1");

        foreach (var item in myList) //This doesn't work because I havn't implemented Ienumerable
            Console.WriteLine(item);

        Console.Read();
    }
}


class LL
{

    private LLNode first;

    public void Add(string s)
    {
        if (this.first == null)
            this.first = new LLNode() { Value = s };
        else
        {
            var node = this.first;
            while (node.Next != null)
                node = node.Next;

            node.Next = new LLNode() { Value = s };
        }
    }


class LLNode
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public LLNode Next { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: [Here](http://codebetter.com/davidhayden/2005/03/08/implementing-ienumerable-and-ienumerator-on-your-custom-objects/) is *not a good tutorial on implementing `IEnumerable` on a custom class. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/474678/A-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Implementing-IEnumerable-I) is a better one.

Comment: Note that, technically, no don't *need* to implement `IEnumerable` to use your class with a `foreach`-loop...

Comment: Yeah, I know but I want to learn how to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is:

(1) Make your class implement IEnumerable<T> where T is the type of the enumerated items. (In your case, it looks like it would be LLNode).

(2) Write a public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator. Implement it using the "yield" keyword.

(3) Add a IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() method and just return GetEnumerator().

The following code should make this clear. Where I have <int>, you should put <LLNode>, assuming that is the correct type.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Demo
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var test = new MyDemo();

            foreach (int item in test)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyDemo: IEnumerable<int>
    {
        public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
        {
            // Your implementation of this method will iterate over your nodes
            // and use "yield return" to return each one in turn.

            for (int i = 10; i <= 20; ++i)
            {
                yield return i;
            }
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
}
```

I would have modified your code to do it properly, but the code you posted won't compile.

[EDIT]

Now you've updated your code, I can see that you want to enumerate the values. Here's the completed code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Demo
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private LL myList = new LL();

        private static void Main()
        {
            var gogo = new Program();
        }

        public Program()
        {
            myList.Add("test");
            myList.Add("test1");

            foreach (var item in myList) // This now works.
                Console.WriteLine(item);

            Console.Read();
        }
    }


    internal class LL: IEnumerable<string>
    {
        private LLNode first;

        public void Add(string s)
        {
            if (this.first == null)
                this.first = new LLNode
                {
                    Value = s
                };
            else
            {
                var node = this.first;
                while (node.Next != null)
                    node = node.Next;

                node.Next = new LLNode
                {
                    Value = s
                };
            }
        }

        public IEnumerator<string> GetEnumerator()
        {
            for (var node = first; node != null; node = node.Next)
            {
                yield return node.Value;
            }
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }

        private class LLNode
        {
            public string Value { get; set; }
            public LLNode Next { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to compile it now, without the foreach loop and WriteLite.

Comment: Thanks it works now. Now I gonna study it.

Answer (score 6):

It's really not that hard. To implement [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) you just need to implement the `GetEnumerator` method.

To do that you need to create another class that implements [IEnumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.aspx). Implementing IEnumerator is pretty easy. Generally you will pass a reference to your collection when you create the enumerator (in GetEnumerator) and the enumerator will keep track of which item is the current item. Then it will provide `MoveNext` which just changes the `Current` to the next item (and returns false if it's at the end of the list) and `Reset` which just sets the `Current` back to *before* the first node.

So in very broad, untested code terms, you need something like:

```
public class MyLinkedListEnumerator : IEnumerator
{
    private LL myList;
    private LLNode current;

    public object Current
    {
       get { return current; }
    }

    public MyLinkedListEnumerator(LL myList) 
    {
        this.myList = myList;
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        if (current == null) {
            current = myList.first;
        }
        else {
            current = current.Next;
        }
        return current != null;
    }

    public void Reset() 
    {
        current = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to point out, C# helps you out with this a lot if you create the `GetEnumerator()` method yourself with `yield` statements etc.

Comment: I get the: Error 1 Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'xx.LL' is less accessible than method 'xx.MyLinkedListEnumerator.MyLinkedListEnumerator(xx.LL)' C:\\xx\Program.cs error

Comment: @Ben: That's probably because your `LL` class is private. Mark it public.